# Remove index.php in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I know it is the most repetitive question of CI.

I am using Kubuntu and have made following changes

```
$config['base_url']='http://localhost/cii/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol']= 'REQUEST_URI';
```

I've kept my .htaccess file where index.php is kept (in the root folder) but am getting following error:

`The requested URL /cii/welcome/second was not found on this server.(404 error)`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|css)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule> 

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
     ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly the problem is due to the *AllowOverride None* of document root path  in apache sites-available configuration file. You need to modify the line containing AllowOverride None to read *AllowOverride All* in the file (/etc/apache2/sites-available/default) to make .htaccess files work as expected. Do restart apache once after made the changes.

```
    <Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
```

[Enabling use of Apache htaccess files.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnablingUseOfApacheHtaccessFiles)

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that the error is because your CI is located at the subfolder /cii but the rewrite rules point to the root folder.
Try adding RewriteBase /cii/ inside the first block.

Comment: If that doesn't do the trick, there are a lot of hints here: http://codeigniter.com/wiki/mod_rewrite/

Comment: my directory structure is /www/cii/

Comment: If your base_url is http://localhost/cii/, then RewriteBase should be /cii/ since it is relative to the domain.

Comment: Add the line "RewriteBase /cii" - without quotes, after the line RewriteEngine On

Comment: Since the base folder is /cii/, also update ErrorDocument 404 /index.php to ErrorDocument 404 /cii/index.php

Comment: Also, are you sure you have enabled mod_rewrite in Apache?

Comment: Are .htaccess files enabled at all?   
Does it work or do any difference at all if you change "RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]" into "RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /cii/index.php/$1 [L]"?